# Perl : parse a file and grab blocks

Tags: perl, config

impossible to parse the file below and grab the blocks in an hash table or simple tab.

I would like to have an hash table with for example

```
[serv-test] => parent=PRODUCTION.Windows,host=1.1.1.1
```

Problem is I can delimit the start of a block (with `/\[.*\]/`) but impossible to delimit the end. The end of my blocks is the start of another.

My file:

```
authreq=false
default.secured=false
port=3181
protocol=TCP
seclevel=2
secured=false
[serv-test]
parent=PRODUCTION.Windows
host=1.1.1.1
[citrix]
parent=PRODUCTION.Windows
host=1.1.1.2
[cluster-serv]
parent=PRODUCTION.Unix._INFRA
host=1.1.1.3
port=3182
```

Comment: It is already implemented in [Config::Simple](https://metacpan.org/pod/Config::Simple)

Comment: What have you tried so far? What errors are you getting from your code? What isn't working for you?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of worrying about getting a hash, be satisfied with getting the data. If you give the top a section name, you have an [INI File](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file):

```
[Default]
authreq=false
default.secured=false
port=3181
protocol=TCP
seclevel=2
secured=false
[serv-test]
parent=PRODUCTION.Windows
host=1.1.1.1
[citrix]
parent=PRODUCTION.Windows
host=1.1.1.2
[cluster-serv]
parent=PRODUCTION.Unix._INFRA
host=1.1.1.3
port=3182
```

Now you can use [Config::IniFiles](http://www.metacpan.org/module/Config::IniFiles):

```
use v5.10;

use Config::IniFiles;

my $cfg = Config::IniFiles->new(
    -file => "test.ini"
    ) or die "@Config::IniFiles::errors";

say "Port is ", $cfg->val( 'Default', 'port' );
say "Cluster host is ", $cfg->val( 'cluster-serv', 'host' );
```

If you really want the hash, that's not so hard:

```
use Config::IniFiles;
use Data::Dumper;

my $cfg = Config::IniFiles->new(
    -file => "test.ini"
    ) or die "@Config::IniFiles::errors";

my %hash;
foreach my $section ( $cfg->Sections ) {
    foreach my $parameter ( $cfg->Parameters( $section ) ) {
        $hash{$section}{$parameter} = $cfg->val( $section, $parameter );
        }
    }

say Dumper \%hash;
```

Now you have:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'citrix' => {
                        'parent' => 'PRODUCTION.Windows',
                        'host' => '1.1.1.2'
                      },
          'Default' => {
                         'secured' => 'false',
                         'port' => '3181',
                         'protocol' => 'TCP',
                         'default.secured' => 'false',
                         'authreq' => 'false',
                         'seclevel' => '2'
                       },
          'serv-test' => {
                           'host' => '1.1.1.1',
                           'parent' => 'PRODUCTION.Windows'
                         },
          'cluster-serv' => {
                              'port' => '3182',
                              'parent' => 'PRODUCTION.Unix._INFRA',
                              'host' => '1.1.1.3'
                            }
        };
```

Comment: Would it not be easier to just [`tie` a hash](https://metacpan.org/pod/Config::IniFiles#USAGE----Tied-Hash) into the Config::IniFiles object?

Comment: Depends on your definition of easy and what you're going to do with the data after. You could `tie` if you like. I tend to not like them since I feel like I'm breaking encapsulation. When I make my own hash I can do it any way that I like or the way the next step expects.

Answer (score 0):

Don't reinvent the wheel. There are plenty of existing modules for working with INI-style files, including [Config::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Config::Tiny), [Config::INI](https://metacpan.org/pod/Config::INI), and [Config::IniFiles](https://metacpan.org/pod/Config::IniFiles), just to name a few.

Comment: Config::IniFiles is what I normally use for this sort of task.